# Javascript - JGRASP- Palindrome

Tags: javascript, boolean, character, case, palindrome

The case is to get strings from a file input to check if the statement is a palindrome or not. For instance, the if input.txt is "Madam I'm Adam.\n racecar \n boat \n 123 321 \n 1234" the output would be

True
True
False
True
False

Here is my Palindrome method:

```js
public static boolean isPalindrome(String word){// Source: http://www.codenuclear.com/java-program-to-check-palindrome/
      String reverse = "";
      
      if(word == null){
         return false;
      }else if(word.length() == 1){
         return true;
      }
      
      for(int i = word.length()-1; i >= 0; i--){
         reverse += word.charAt(i);
      }
      
      if(word.equalsIgnoreCase(reverse)){
         return true;
      }
      
      return false;
   }
```

The output so far has been:

False
True
False
True
False

I think the problem is with the statement "Madam I'm Adam" and the uppercase getting in the way. How can I run the code to ignore the Upper Case to get the palindrome to be true? I know there's a .equalsIgnoreUpperCase() method or some sort.

Comment: Characters case is one thing, The other I see: "Madam I'm Adam" is not strictly speaking a palindrome. unless there is unspoken rule concerning characters others than letters.

Comment: `Madam I'm Adam`  reverses in `madA m'I madam`

Answer (score 0):

It fails because of the spaces, the <'> char and the letter-case in the 'Madam I'm Adam' string.

Edit the function to ignore these characters and other characters that you don't want your algorithm to consider, or better yet use ascii to verify each character in the string before you check whether it is a palindrome, 
then convert all the characters to lower case using toLowerCase() method and it should work like you want it to.